# When will PLANCK release all-sky CMB anisotropy measurements?

Tags: cosmic-microwave-background

After hearing so much about PLANCK, people these days are still constraining models with WMAP results. When will PLANCK finally release its much more superior data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dear Felix, by the middle of 2010, Planck had already covered 100% of the skies for the first time. The first version of the final results are scheduled to be released in January 2013 (previously by the end of 2012), see

> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck_(spacecraft)#Results

However, during a January 2011 Planck conference in Paris, they have released "early results"

> http://arxiv.org/abs/1101.2022

It's mostly about the health status - the spacecraft seems to work astoundingly well so far. The package is available at

> http://www.rssd.esa.int/index.php?project=Planck
>   http://www.sciops.esa.int/index.php?project=PLANCK&page=Planck_Published_Papers

The second link contains 25 papers on the arXiv. Again, the maps and timelines will be released in January 2013 according to the current plan - see the conclusions of the 1101.2022 paper above.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed information. One question though. WMAP has released data several times (5 year result, 7 year result) as it gains more data and reduces uncertainties. For Planck, after the expected release of data in Jan 2013, will there be more future releases that bring significant improvement in data quality? Or is the 2013 release more or less what cosmologists will be using for the next couple of years to study models?